# Parenting to bone make object move

Tags: bones, transforms, parent

I'm trying to make clothes for Manuel Bastioni generated meshes.
So I can parent a mesh to an armature and it keeps its transformation. However, as soon as choose a specific bone, the mesh undergoes undesired translations and rotations.
Here it is before parenting to a bone, but already parented to the armature:
[image: Before bone parenting]

Now parented to one of the armature's bones:
[image: After bone parenting]

I can painstakingly replace the mesh afterwards but it's undergone too much transform to make it a matter of a couple of rotations.

N.B.: I cleared all position and rotation on the original mesh before parenting and it was in perfect position.

Any idea why it moves and how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the object your are trying to parent to a bone already has a parent. If that is true, then try removing the object's parent then parent it to the bone. This may not always be easy, depending on your object structures and dependencies. But at least it should solve the problem of the object jumping when you parent it to a bone.